# How to create jar with aspectj? Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I want to create jar file with support AspectJ. 
My manifest.mf(use default-package):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: gui
\n
```

I added manifest in eclipse. My errors:

```
exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/aspectj/lang/signature
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: classpath
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknow Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknow Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknow Source)
could not find the main class: gui. Program will exit.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry for my language
Cheers

Comment: Where do you put your main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the manifest file to

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_11-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: gui
Class-Path: AspectJ.jar
```

Use this file as manifest ([using jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) ) of your executable jar.

Comment: Class-Path: AspectJ.jar?
You thing about aspectjrt.jar??
Without Main-Class?

Comment: Class-Path:? AspectJ.jar where is that file? I add this: jar cvfm gui.jar manifest.mf and i have the same error. Thank for patience

Comment: I just put jar file name for Aspectj. You need to put the correct jar file name.